# Dynamically allocate struct of char array and int array

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am trying to use `malloc` to allocate memory for a `struct` containing a `char` array and an `int` array.  I will be populating these two arrays with information from a file whose length I will not know in advance.

```
typedef struct bulk_data{
    int *l_bulk_pos_arr;
    char (*l_bulk_anc_arr)[10001];
}bulk_data;
```

I am still learning memory allocation, but what I imagine here is that since the size of each `char` array element is fixed, I shouldn't have to loop through that array to allocate memory. At this point I now know the number of array elements I need (`n_rows`). I have tried the following (obviously not all at the same time):

```
struct bulk_data *bulk_counts;
    bulk_counts = malloc(sizeof(bulk_data)); // 1st attempt
    bulk_counts = (bulk_data *)malloc(sizeof(bulk_data)); // 2nd
    bulk_counts = malloc(sizeof(bulk_data) * n_rows); // 3rd
    bulk_counts = (bulk_data *)malloc(sizeof(bulk_data) * n_rows); // 4th
```

No errors at compile time, but it appears that the above listed attempts aren't allocating the space properly:

```
(gdb) p bulk_counts->l_bulk_anc_arr
$1 = (char (*)[10001]) 0x0
(gdb) p bulk_counts->l_bulk_anc_arr[0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

(gdb) p bulk_data->l_bulk_pos_arr
$2 = (int *) 0x0
(gdb) p bulk_data->l_bulk_pos_arr[0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

I would like to know how I can allocate memory for this stated case, but also in the case when you don't know the number of chars in each `char` array element.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're really using C and you have a decent compiler, you don't need to cast the result of your `malloc`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l_bulk_anc_arr` is a pointer to *an array of `10001` `char`s*. It is not an array.

You still have to allocate memory for it.

```
struct bulk_data *bulk_counts;
bulk_counts = malloc(sizeof(bulk_data));
bulk_counts->l_bulk_pos_arr = malloc( /*some size*/ );
bulk_counts->l_bulk_anc_arr = malloc(10001);
```

Now, you can use:

```
(*bulk_counts->l_bulk_anc_arr)[0] = 'a';
(*bulk_counts->l_bulk_anc_arr)[1000] = '\0';
```

or

```
bulk_counts->l_bulk_anc_arr[0][0] = 'a';
bulk_counts->l_bulk_anc_arr[0][1000] = '\0';
```